# How to handle incorrect application version in aws elastic beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently setting up an automated deployment pipeline for my Elastic Beanstalk environment with GitHub, and I've run into an issue with versioning.

To illustrate the issue, consider this example:

For main, I have version-202, which is working fine.
For dev, I have version-201, which is also working fine.
However, when I push a new change, the version number is incremented as expected (e.g., dev moves to version-203). But, AWS Elastic Beanstalk then throws an error, stating that it is expecting version-202, not the new version-203. The error message is:

error: Incorrect application version "app-5680588874-222" (deployment 9). Expected version "app-5681075575-223-dev-dev" (deployment 10).

Here's a snippet from my eb-deploy.yml file:

```
name: Deploy Node app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

env:
  APP_NAME_APP1: appv1
  APP_NAME_APP2: appv2
  AWS_REGION: ap-south-1
  PIPELINE_ID: ${GITHUB_RUN_ID}-${GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER}

on:
  push:
    branches: [main, dev]

jobs:
  create_eb_version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get sanitized branch name
        run: |
          ENVIRONMENT=""
          if [ "${{ github.ref }}" == 'refs/heads/main' ]; then
            ENVIRONMENT="prod"
          elif [ "${{ github.ref }}" == 'refs/heads/dev' ]; then
            ENVIRONMENT="dev"
          fi
          echo "SANITIZED_REF=$ENVIRONMENT-$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/} | sed 's/\//-/g')" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ""
          aws-secret-access-key: ""
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}

      - name: Set S3_BUCKET and ENVIRONMENT_NAME for App1
        run: |
          if [ "${{ github.ref }}" == 'refs/heads/main' ]; then
            echo "S3_BUCKET=environment-prod" >> $GITHUB_ENV
            echo "ENVIRONMENT_NAME=environment-prod-env" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          elif [ "${{ github.ref }}" == 'refs/heads/dev' ]; then
            echo "S3_BUCKET=environment-dev" >> $GITHUB_ENV
            echo "ENVIRONMENT_NAME=environment-dev-env" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          fi

      - name: Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk
        run: |
          APP_NAME=""
          if [ "${{ github.ref }}" == 'refs/heads/main' ]; then
            APP_NAME=${{ env.APP_NAME_APP1 }}
          elif [ "${{ github.ref }}" == 'refs/heads/dev' ]; then
            APP_NAME=${{ env.APP_NAME_APP2 }}
          fi

          echo "Creating Source Bundle"
          zip -r $APP_NAME.zip .

          AWS_VERSION_LABEL="$APP_NAME-${{env.PIPELINE_ID}}-${{env.SANITIZED_REF}}"
          S3_KEY="$AWS_VERSION_LABEL.zip"

          echo "Uploading Source Bundle to S3"
          aws s3 cp $APP_NAME.zip s3://${{env.S3_BUCKET}}/${S3_KEY} --region ${{env.AWS_REGION}}

          echo "Creating Elastic Beanstalk version"
          aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name $APP_NAME --version-label $AWS_VERSION_LABEL --region ${{env.AWS_REGION}} --source-bundle S3Bucket=${{env.S3_BUCKET}},S3Key=${S3_KEY}

          echo "Deploy init"
          aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --application-name $APP_NAME --environment-name ${{env.ENVIRONMENT_NAME}} --version-label $AWS_VERSION_LABEL --region ${{env.AWS_REGION}}
          echo "Deploy finished"
```

Any help with resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Is there something I am missing in the configuration of my eb-deploy.yml file? Is there a specific setting in AWS Elastic Beanstalk that needs to be configured for version increments during automated deployments?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

tried "codepipeline" and version change too